# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages (phpseclib/bcmath_compat)

Tags: php, composer-php, phpseclib

I don't understand this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- don't install phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.3|don't install php 7.3.13
- composer.json/composer.lock requires php 7.3.* -> satisfiable by php[7.3.13].
- Installation request for phpseclib/bcmath_compat 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/bcmath_compat[1.0.3].
```

I'm running PHP 7.3.13.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of php are you running? Sounds like it wants 7.3+

Comment: I'm running PHP 7.3.13.

Comment: What are you doing to provoke this error?

Comment: This is due to some wonkiness specific to Heroku. https://github.com/phpseclib/bcmath_compat/issues/1#issuecomment-573112000 elaborates.

Answer (score 6):

This is basically a new requirement of a package that was recently updated, for which your app has a loose version requirement.

A simple (albeit temporary) fix for it would be to make use of Composer's [require inline alias](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias)

TL;DR: Assuming you're trying to install a Laravel product, just run this at the root of your project:

```
composer require moontoast/math "1.1.2 as 1.999.999"
```